# Convert Pipelined RDD to Dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

This is how my pipelined RDD looks:

```
[([3.0, 12.0, 8.0, 49.0, 27.0], 7968.0),
 ([165.0, 140.0, 348.0, 615.0, 311.0], 165.0)]
```

I want to convert this to a dataframe. I have tried converting the first element (in square brackets) to an RDD and the second one to an RDD and then convert them individually to dataframes. I have also tried setting a schema and converting it but it has not worked. Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `myrdd.toDF()`? You can also specify column names: `myrdd.toDF(["col1", "col2"])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten your RDD before converting to a `DataFrame`:

```
df=rdd.map(lambda (x,y): x+[y]).toDF()
```

You can specify the `schema` argument of `toDF()` to get meaningful column names and/or types.

Comment: This is not true. You do not have the flatten the rdd first. You can call `toDF()` directly.